# What are the changes between the touring version of "The Play That Goes Wrong" and the licensed stage version?

Tags: textual-history, the-play-that-goes-wrong

I saw *The Play That Goes Wrong* when it came through my town, having greatly enjoyed the excerpt I'd found online of the show. [It's now available to be licensed for professional, community, and school theater](https://www.dramatists.com/cgi-bin/db/single.asp?key=5523), but as I understand it, some parts of it have been simplified for the smaller stage. Is there a listing of what the differences are? Are they purely technical (for one, I see that it's arranged to be a single-level set, although the script pages I've seen posted online seem to still reference the elevator and second floor gags), or was the plot changed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a partial answer in anticipation of receiving my full copy of the script, but I spoke with the people at Dramatists Play Service, who license the show in the United States, and they have stated that the text indicating that the play has been simplified and is on a single level is for [the one-act version of the show](https://www.dramatists.com/cgi-bin/db/single.asp?index=0&key=6183), much closer to [the performance at The Royal Variety Performance in 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOWO4gq-whg). The licensed [full version of the show](https://www.dramatists.com/cgi-bin/db/single.asp?key=5523) uses the same script as the touring Broadway production. My scan of excerpts I have found for the two scripts matches that statement.